# How come all money making methods online are haram?

Tags: practical-islam, finance

So recently my friend has told me due to the ayah ( يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَوْفُوا بِالْعُقُودِ..)
Which means "Quran 5:1 O you who believe fullfil contracts."

Now people mention how web scraping is haram since it's a violation to TOS.
And doing work on a site requiring you to be 18+ years old is haram since it's a violation to TOS if your below it and even if you don't do work you just literally access that website and whatever useful stuff they have in you use for your own business.

I find it personally very hard to make money online like dropshipping (can't advertise without music)/Youtube (can't make money from adsense and many sponsers will require you to add background music)/ Day trading/ Real estate (Need to take loans or you can argue do the islamic finance still not worth it because it'll require capital and extensive knowledge).   and so on it's pretty much close to impossible to run a proper business online without including music

And even like for me i want to sell social media accounts that aren't stolen nor have any ill intent or used for any wrong purposes but i can't now because "TOS violation haram" even though it's legal. And most social media services which use automated activity that doesn't harm no one nor affects the platform but "TOS violation haram"

Drives me insane honestly knowing this. It's halal to not read TOS based on the sheikh assim alhakim and no one reads it, like literally i looked into it it's made so that if you want to sue the company they'll be covered. They include as much stuff in the TOS as possible even if it doesn't make any sense, and if we were to read TOS it would take us 250 working hours, like even lawyers that make these terms of services don't read it i went OCD and started looking into that as well.

And it goes even deeper cause here in saudi we have a test called "qudrat" which is basically like an SAT for your college acceptance and before you take the exam you literally have to write down the rules of the exam in which it says don't send any of the questions after the exam and what's funny is no one follows it I'm talking the entire arab nation 50+ million and they violate it and what's funnier is you cannot study these tests without the questions leaked cause the books used to study it are from teachers who gathered these questions and just add them onto the book and create formulas and whatnot to solve these questions, so does that mean me studying this and getting into college is haram?

My question leads to this if i do something non sinister or doesn't affect anyone infact just boost businesses and do ethical activity but in line 10041413 in a TOS it says your not allowed to do automated activity does that make my money haram?

Please give me an answer cause I've been going insane past 2 months on this it's like i cannot do anything at all.
I can talk more but i don't want this to be too long.

Answer (score 0):

Salam alaikoum, all praise be to Allah, I will attempt to answer the best I can,

This seems like a case of waswas, with you admittedly going "OCD" about this, I recommend you seek counseling or personally address a trusted Sheikh regarding these issues. Even in the hypothetical case where there is no way of you earning money in your cirumstances, this is a matter of dunya and you should not be distressed regarding this for long as Allah (swt) is the most merciful and is the best of planners.

It seems like you are of a young age and I recommend that you pursue seeking knowledge and reach a state of Tawakkul rather than aspire for dunya as Allah's Messenger (pbuh) has said that "Allah makes the way to Jannah easy for him who treads the path in search of knowledge" [Riyad as-Salihin 1381, Sahih].

Regarding your Saudi GAT, I do not understand the specifics of the question being asked but cheating in such exams are forbidden as our Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) has said that "whoever cheats is not one of us" [Jamiâat Tirmidhi 1315], this is regarding every dealing especially in a school setting where cheating would be a breach of trust between the teacher and the student.

From readily available information, many of these terms of service contraints are done in accordance with the Children's Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA) in the United States of America which allows such personal data about minors to be transmitted with parental consent. If you have agreed to such contracts without reading them and have violated them out of ignorance, they shall be forgiven as our Beloved Prophet (pbuh) has said that "Allah has forgiven my nation for mistakes and forgetfulness, and what they are forced to do" [Sunan ibn Majah 2045].

Regarding verse 1 of Surah al-Maidah in the Noble Quran, Tafsir Saâdi (p. 347) states that this refers to covenants including those, among others, between the individual and his Lord, and with their parents, companions, and relatives to uphold ties with them regardless of periods of ease or difficulty, and covenants between the individual and other people, in transactions such as buying and selling, renting, and so on, and covenants that involve giving something for free, such as gifts and the like. It is worth noting that the Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) adds that "the Muslims will be held to their conditions, except the conditions that make the lawful unlawful, or the unlawful lawful" [Jamiâat Tirmidhi 1352, Sahih].

I hope this has been useful and Allah (swt) knows best.

Comment: I'd like to understand though because for instance instagram pages and youtube channels get sold at a multi million dollar level without any issues. And when i ask how is this allowed since it violates a TOS they mention "instagram doesn't monitor"

Like @daquan a famous page on instagram was acquired for 85 million dollars without any problem.

Just trying to understand like in a circumstance in which your doing something that isn't illegal nor is monitored and the platform doesn't care at all. Is it still haram?
Like i understand being strict but there needs to be some logic here.